# Sum formated times from Datatable into an textBox

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, types, sum

I am trying to sum up values out of an datatable created out of an database query.

The times in MySQL DB are formatted like HH:mm:ss (ss is always 00)

I already had this running i just was unhappy with the result as for example 25 h as result resulted in 1.01:00:00 or 1 day and 1 hour when i wanted to receive 25 h as it is saved in the database, changing data type in mysql is not an option for me, as i have a bunch of calc's that need those as data type time.

Right now the code is not longer able to show the result in a textBox as I have more a less an error:

> "Invalid use of aggregate function Sum () and Type: String."

As far as I understood I can not sum strings, just time and numbers, however I could do it before formatting time right when it gets pulled out of the db.

I did search in google for a good solution for a couple of days now, but the only options I see are thinks that I already tried around on my own (of cause tested again just more errors)

However here is the required code snippet:

```
MySqlCommand cmddttoday = conn.CreateCommand();
cmddttoday.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmddttoday.CommandText = "SELECT day, month, date_format (start, '%H:%i') start, date_format (stop, '%H:%i') stop, date_format (total, '%H:%i') total FROM arbeitszeiten WHERE username = '" + textBoxusername.Text + "' and day = '" + today + "' and month = '" + month + "' and year = '" + thisyear + "'";

cmddttoday.ExecuteScalar();

DataTable dttimetoday = new DataTable();

MySqlDataAdapter datadatoday = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmddttoday);
datadatoday.Fill(dttimetoday);

textBoxtimetoday.Text = dttimetoday.Compute("SUM(total)", "").ToString();

dttimetoday.Columns["day"].ColumnName = "Tag";
dttimetoday.Columns["month"].ColumnName = "Monat";
dttimetoday.Columns["start"].ColumnName = "Arbeit aufgenommen";
dttimetoday.Columns["stop"].ColumnName = "Arbeit abgelegt";
dttimetoday.Columns["total"].ColumnName = "Zeit gesammt";
```

Keep in mind, yes it does not work like this but without the format on total in the query it shows like explained before as 1.01:00:00

I would be very happy if we found a solution for this meanwhile annoying problem.

Thanks for your burning braincells ;)

Comment: Please don't use string concatenation on SQL scripts because of sql injections. You need to use cmd.parameters.addwithvalue it's critical mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think using TIMESTAMPDIFF would be way easier to calculate the timedifference in minutes directly. From there you can use SUM to calculate the total of minutes. To get the hours you can then simply divide by 60. This would look like this:

```
SELECT SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(Minute,start, end)/60) from arbeitszeiten
```

Check out this Fiddle: [Link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vSjFyAHjNDPLCHR13kJwyi/1)

EDIT:

If thats the case, you have to use linq. The error you get is because the datatable column "total" is of the datatype string. Since you cant Sum a string this wont work. You cant convert withing the SUM function either since the Compute method requests a number inside of the brackets.

With linq you can do it like this:

```
 textBoxtimetoday.Text = dttimetoday.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Field<string>(4))).ToString();
```

but you have to replace `date_format (total, '%H:%i') total` with `date_format (total, '%H.%i') total`

Comment: i dont know so much about that .. noticed my first comment was complete nonsence so again:

we would end up having values like 1.75 hours which is very unfriendly and unnatural to read as 1 hour and 45 minutes, there again i see potential problem on the human side when editing / updating values

Comment: "The input string has the wrong format." .. as i do not understand right now what you did there i dont know where that coming from .. i assume from the format when fulling it out of the db ?

Comment: deleting the "date_format (total, '%H:%i') " in query i not the solutions as i hoped ^^

Comment: MSDN states that the default datatype of a column is string: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/0c5wf85e(v=vs.140)#setdatatype
So if you dont change it explicitly before filling the data it will be a string

Comment: okay, i dont think this will make a difference in calling data from db but my columns that we need right here (start, stop, total) are set as datatyp time. does that mean i have to change it ? iam sorry if i dont get your meaning right here, all i know about programming i had to learn on my own without any teaching or something so i guess I just missed what you tried to tell me with your last message

Comment: Just use the Linq statement I provided: textBoxtimetoday.Text = dttimetoday.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Field<string>("total"))).ToString();

Comment: allready did that. thats where i got the "The input string has the wrong format." from

Comment: replace date_format (total, '%H:%i') total with date_format (total, '%H.%i')

Comment: i did and now it tells me that total is not a part of the table

Comment: decimal a = x.AsEnumerable().Sum(r => Convert.ToDecimal(r.Field<string>(0)));

Comment: And I advise you very very much to study this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/getting-started-with-linq